# 34/5000 why did you delete my post?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

Good morning,
why did you delete my post? [Error on 'Newsletter Subscribers'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158341/error-on-newsletter-subscribers/158344)
Could you give feedback please?

Comment: you should check [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @marius indicates using an answer to indicate you have the same problem is not the correct approach. A good approach if you have the same issue as the original poster is to upvote  the question, this will tag you on future answers.

Comment: For this type of things you can post a comment on users question, but for that you have to earn 50 rep in this site

Answer (score 8):

Your answer was deleted because is was not an answer.
The Stackexchange network has a Q&A format where the question should describe the problem you are facing, and the answers should solve or try to solve the problem in the questions.
Posting "I have the same problem" as an answer does not count as an answer. It does not help the person who posted the question and it does not help future readers. It is just noise.